# What's wrong with my equations?

Tags: matrices

A roadside fruit stand sells apples at 75 cents a pound, peaches at 90 cents a pound, and pears at 60 cents a pound. Muriel buys 18 pounds of fruit at total cost of 13.80 dollars. Her peaches and pears together cost 1.80  more than her apples. Set up a linear system for the number of pounds of apples, peaches and pears that she bought.

I have made an equation and I'm not so sure about it. I know that there is something's wrong with this equation. Can you tell me what is it? 
Here it is:
$$
75x+90y+60z=1380                              
$$
$$
x+y+z=18
$$
$$
-1.80x+y+z=0                           
$$

Comment: You should learn LaTeX markup!

Comment: @user114811 The $3$rd equation is a bit wrong. You can look up for the correct equation in the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that Muriel has bought $x$ pounds of apples, $y$ pounds of peaches and $z$ pounds of pears. Assuming $1$ pound = $100$ cents (I do not know the exact conversion),

$$x+y+z = 18$$
$$0.75x + 0.90y + 0.60z = 13.80$$
$$0.75x + 1.80 = 0.90y + 0.60z$$

**NOTE:** It is mentioned that "peaches and pears together cost $1.80$ **more** than her apples". Also it should have been $90y+60z$ in your last equation as we are talking about the prices.

Comment: Now I understand. It's a great help!!

Answer (score 1):

Your last equation is wrong.

As you identified in your first equation, the price of apples is $75x$, the price of peaches $90y$ and the price of pears $60z$.

> Her peaches and pears together cost 1.80 more than her apples

The price of apples plus $180$ cents is the same as the price of peaches and pears together.